# Bootstrap carousel slider arrows error

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

As the title says i have a problem with the arrows in the carousel. The arrows go up and merge with the navbar but i can still click to change the image. I've added background images as covers and i modified the code a little to the point i cant find out what is the problem. Can you help me here? How can i get the arrows down again and why is that happening?

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Web Paintings</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">

        </script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- Navigation -->

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top margin-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Web Paintings</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-database"></span>Paintings</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-book"></span>Contact</a>
                    </li>
                            <li class="slide"><a href="#" class="btn-slide1"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>Register</a></li>
                            <li class="slide"><a href="#" class="btn-slide2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                </ul>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>   



            <div class="margin-top">
                             <!-- START OF CAROUSEL -->
                            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                              <!-- Carousel items -->
                              <div class="carousel-inner">
                                 <div class="item active ad1">
                                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                                       <h4 class="mycaption">First Thumbnail label</h4>
                                       <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="item ad2">
                                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                                        <h4 class="mycaption">Second Thumbnail label</h4>
                                        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="item ad3">
                                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                                       <h4 class="mycaption">Third Thumbnail label</h4>
                                       <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <!-- Carousel nav -->
                              <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                              <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
                            </div>


                               <!-- END OF CAROUSEL -->

                </div>
             </div>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.marginTop{
  margin-top:60px;
}
.navbar { 
  min-height: 32px !important; 
}
 .navbar .navbar-brand{ 
  padding: 0 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 38px;
  height: 38px; 
}
 .navbar .navbar-nav > li > a { 
  padding-top: 0px; 
  padding-bottom: 0px; 
  line-height: 38px; 
}
 .navbar .navbar-toggle { 
  margin-top: 3px; 
  margin-bottom: 0px; 
  padding: 8px 9px; 
}
 .navbar .navbar-collapse {
  border-color: #2f2f2f;
}
ul.nav a:hover {   
    color: #129CF3 !important;
}

#myCarousel {
    width: 100%;
}
.carousel-control {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.carousel-inner .item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.ad1 {
    background: url(images/paint1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
}
.ad2 {
    background: url(images/paint2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
}
.ad3 {
    background: url(images/paint3.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
}
.mycaption {
  color: white; 
    font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; letter-spacing: -1px;  
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `line-height` on `.carousel-control`  Depend on your `.carousel-inner .item > height`

```
.carousel-control {
   line-height:400px;
   font-size:100px !important; 
   width:80px !important;
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.marginTop{
  margin-top:60px;
}
.navbar { 
  min-height: 32px !important; 
}
 .navbar .navbar-brand{ 
  padding: 0 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 38px;
  height: 38px; 
}
 .navbar .navbar-nav > li > a { 
  padding-top: 0px; 
  padding-bottom: 0px; 
  line-height: 38px; 
}
 .navbar .navbar-toggle { 
  margin-top: 3px; 
  margin-bottom: 0px; 
  padding: 8px 9px; 
}
 .navbar .navbar-collapse {
  border-color: #2f2f2f;
}
ul.nav a:hover {   
    color: #129CF3 !important;
}

#myCarousel {
    width: 100%;
}
.carousel-control {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.carousel-inner .item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
    .carousel-control {
   line-height:400px;
   font-size:100px !important; 
   width:80px !important;
}
.ad1 {
    background: url(images/paint1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
}
.ad2 {
    background: url(images/paint2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
}
.ad3 {
    background: url(images/paint3.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
}
.mycaption {
  color: white; 
    font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; letter-spacing: -1px;  
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Web Paintings</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">

        </script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- Navigation -->

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top margin-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Web Paintings</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-database"></span>Paintings</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-book"></span>Contact</a>
                    </li>
                            <li class="slide"><a href="#" class="btn-slide1"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>Register</a></li>
                            <li class="slide"><a href="#" class="btn-slide2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                </ul>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>   



            <div class="margin-top">
                             <!-- START OF CAROUSEL -->
                            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                              <!-- Carousel items -->
                              <div class="carousel-inner">
                                 <div class="item active ad1">
                                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                                       <h4 class="mycaption">First Thumbnail label</h4>
                                       <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="item ad2">
                                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                                        <h4 class="mycaption">Second Thumbnail label</h4>
                                        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="item ad3">
                                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                                       <h4 class="mycaption">Third Thumbnail label</h4>
                                       <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <!-- Carousel nav -->
                              <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                              <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
                            </div>


                               <!-- END OF CAROUSEL -->

                </div>
             </div>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Might also be nice to increase the `font-size` to something like `100px`, [something like this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZyYyWg)

Comment: It worked. Thank you a lot! Could you please explain to me why this happened if you want? Also, i have one more question to ask. Do you know how i can reduce the arrow's area that's clickable? Thank you again.

Comment: reduce the arrow's area that's clickable? - reduce width i have update my answer

Comment: @JoelLi If you inspect the element in your browser, you can see the `carousel-control` class is partly under the menu. Because the line-height was too small, the arrow disappeared under the menu.

Comment: I've inspected it and i see that the whole carousel merges with the navbar, it gets inside the navbar. I see that we managed to fix the arrows by enlarging them somehow but if you inspect the code you'll see that the carousel gets in the area of the navbar.